# CPanel for single user of VPS

Tags: vps

I just purchased some VPS hosting and part of the package was the installation of CPanel. This is good because I have used CPanel before as a user with various hosting providers. However, what I didn't realize is that the CPanel setup I was given is for resellers.

I am using this VPS as my own PHP/MySQL development platform and the only user would be me. I was hoping to get a CPanel "user" interface that would allow me to create/manage and files and setup a FTP account. I do have an SSH account but I am new to Linux and unsure how to even SSH to the box (don't flame me please). I was hoping to learn these things as I go while using CPanel to help me manage files for Apache.

So I have a few options. I could opt to have two other control panels installed instead of CPanel.

- DirectAdmin
- Plesk

But these may be setup in the same reseller mode as CPanel.

Or I guess I could just setup one account under CPanel and use that the manage the things I need on the server. Any thoughts on the best way to go? If anyone has any links on how to setup CPanel in the way I was describing it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 2):

When I started running my own server, I found [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) to be an excellent tool for administering the server. It's not as simple as cPanel to use, but infinitely cheaper. It's far easier than learning terminal commands, too.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a good tool. I am thinking I might just try and learn it on my own without a control panel. All I need is FTP and SSH access. This could be a good learning experience.

Comment: @webworm Webmin is good for much more than just File access. It allows you to configure everything else in a nice, easy to use interface. While you can do it in SSH, its going to be much harder

Comment: Is it hard to install? Problem is a I am really new to Linux. I can get access to the console via SSH but I am unsure how to install a package like Webmin

Comment: @webworm: You don't mention which flavour of Linux you're using, but here's how I do it in Ubuntu:
1. Download the latest version of webmin:
> wget http://www.webmin.com/download/deb/webmin-current.deb
2. Execute the package (this will fail):
> sudo dpkg -i webmin-current.deb
3. Install missing dependancies and continue installation:
> sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 1):

ISPConfig is a better suited alternative to CPanel.

Comment: +1 -- That does look pretty good. Looking forward to trying it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I often see people confuse WHM with cPanel.

```
1. WHM = Server Management
2. cPanel = Domain Management
```

What you have to do is,

```
Create the domain from your WHM >> Account Functions >> Create a New Account option.
Now login to your cPanel of the domain using the login details you just created to
manage your domains in cPanel.
```

For the complete WHM & cPanel docs,

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/WebHome

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/

-$

Answer (score 0):

If you have purchased cPanel, I would suggest you stick with cPanel since it's much easier to manage and has excellent support.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need to do is assign your single account full privileges in WHM (the reseller bit of cPanel that I guess you are logging into) and once this is done just login via cPanel.

The first thing you should do is go to "Add a Package" in the left hand menu, fill this in choosing a package name and give as much resources as you have available to this package.

Once this is done go to "Create a New Account" and setup your domain choosing the package you just created and assigning a password and click Create.

When this is setup you will be able to login to your cPanel using the server IP on port 2082 in the format http://IP:2082 in your browser e.g. http://123.123.123.123:2082 entering the username and password for the account you just created, this will log you into the user level section of cPanel instead of the reseller WHM.